# Getting the average value of the list items value

Tags: list, sharepoint-addin

Okay so, I'm getting my sharepoint listItems, and i want to count the average value of "_x0072_zb6" which is a price column, right now i'm getting the following error: Cannot read the property value of null ( elmt )
and Error 403, forbidden, please help!

```
function VisaLista() {
    namn = document.getElementById("txtNamn");
    var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
    camlQuery.set_viewXml(
    "<Where>" +
    "<And>" +
    "<Eq><FieldRef Name='Title'/><Value Type='Text'>" + namn + "</Value></Eq>" +
    "<Or>" +
    "<Eq><FieldRef Name='Prioritet'/><Value Type='Text'>Hög</Value></Eq>" +
    "<Eq><FieldRef Name='Status'/><Value Type='Text'>Startad</Value></Eq>" +
    "</Or>" +
    "</And>" +
    "</Where>");
    listItems1 = list.getItems(camlQuery);
    clientContext.load(listItems1);
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(OnSuccessVisa, OnFail);
}

   function OnSuccessVisa() {
        var listEnumerator = listItems1.getEnumerator();
        var elmt = 0;
        while (listEnumerator.moveNext()) {
            var currentItem = listEnumerator.get_current();
            elmt = (currentItem.get_item('_x0072_zb6'));

            var sum = 0;
            for (var i = 0; i < elmt.length; i++) {
                sum += parseInt(elmt[i]);
            }

            var avg = sum / elmt.length;
        }
        $("#Kategori1").text = "Medelvärdet för dessa ordrar: " + avg
    }
```

Comment: Do you get the same error when trying to retrieve other fields too, including standard fields rather than your own custom fields?

Comment: I think `set_viewXml` includes `<Query></Query>` tag as well. And `<Where>` should be inside `<Query>` tag